# how to sole pubspec error in androind studio

Tags: android

getting error in pubspec.yaml i am not able to sort it out...pls help

CODE:

```
name: i_am_rich
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
    assets    :
        - images/ diamond.png
```

Error:

```
 C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 18, column 15: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?
   ╷
18 │     assets    :
   │               ^
   ╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\BHASKAR\Documents\appdev\i_am_rich\i_am_rich\pubspec.yaml
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary spaces between `assets` and `:` here:

`assets    :`

it should be
`assets:`